# change Legends(ScreenOverlay) for different eye alt in KML file

Tags: scale, legend, kml, google-earth

In the Google Earth application i'm working on, should be shown up different legends(ScreenOverlay) for different eye-alt positions. Something like a changing color-scale which represent the intensity of fires who are shown in rectangles which will down-scale with the eye-alt. 
So my idea was to make a lot of small regions(so 5 of 5 degrees) over the hole globe and shown up to different LoDs, different Legends.
But that way is very involved and will take a lot performance from the application.
So, is there a way to make this easy and more sophisticated ?

Comment: Can you try setting just one region, near the center of the Earth, and give it a really big LOD? Not sure how well it would work, but might be worth a shot.

Comment: i´d tried it,but it does not work well. Because at low resolutions even a very small region is nearly never in the screen. For high resolutions it worked well with a few small regions equally scattered over the globe.